# Shopware 6 export listining on event not working

Tags: php, shopware6

i want to create a plugin to add additional data to the product export feed. Currently i create a new subscriber and register the subscriber in the services.xml.

But the Plugin is not listining to the defined event.

src/Subscriber/ProductFeedExportSubscriber.php

```
<?php

namespace uniqueweb\AdvancedProductFeedExport\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Content\ProductExport\Event\ProductExportRenderBodyContextEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class ProductFeedExportSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductExportRenderBodyContextEvent::NAME => 'onRenderBodyContextEvent'
        ];
    }

    public function onRenderBodyContextEvent(ProductExportRenderBodyContextEvent $event): array
    {
        $context = $event->getContext();
        $context['property_groups'] = 'test groups';

        return $context;
    }
}
```

src/Resources/config/services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="https://symfony.com/schema/dic/services https://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="uniqueweb\AdvancedProductFeedExport\Subscriber\ProductFeedExportSubscriber">
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

shopware/core/Content/ProductExport/Event/ProductExportRenderBodyContextEvent.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Shopware\Core\Content\ProductExport\Event;

use Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event;

class ProductExportRenderBodyContextEvent extends Event
{
    public const NAME = 'product_export.render.body_context';

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $context;

    public function __construct(array $context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getContext(): array
    {
        return $this->context;
    }

    public function setContext(array $context): void
    {
        $this->context = $context;
    }
}
```

The event is dispatched in the following file: shopware/core/Content/ProductExport/Service/ProductExportGenerator.php:177

```
$productContext = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(
            new ProductExportRenderBodyContextEvent(
                [
                    'productExport' => $productExport,
                    'context' => $context,
                ]
            )
        );

        $body = '';
        while ($productResult = $iterator->fetch()) {
            /** @var ProductEntity $product */
            foreach ($productResult->getEntities() as $product) {
                $data = $productContext->getContext();
                $data['product'] = $product;

                if ($productExport->isIncludeVariants() && !$product->getParentId() && $product->getChildCount() > 0) {
                    continue; // Skip main product if variants are included
                }
                if (!$productExport->isIncludeVariants() && $product->getParentId()) {
                    continue; // Skip variants unless they are included
                }

                $body .= $this->productExportRender->renderBody($productExport, $context, $data);
            }

            if ($exportBehavior->batchMode()) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

If i placed a breakpoint before and after the dispatch xdebug stop, but the event is not fired. I need to modify the values in the $data array and add values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should be registering the listener:

```php
return [
    ProductExportRenderBodyContextEvent::class => 'onRenderBodyContextEvent',
];
```

Unfortunately this is a little confusing and I'm actually not quite sure what the `NAME` constant is there for, it seems to be unused.